# PUT/Update/Delete item in nested Appsync array. React, useReducer, Apollo

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-appsync

I have an object in my schema which has an array like so:

```
type Foo @aws_cognito_user_pool {
   id: ID!
   name: String
   comments: [Comment]
   createdAt: AWSDateTime
}
```

the input and Comment Type look like so:

```
input FooInput @aws_cognito_user_pool {
       name: String
       comments: [CommentInput]
 }

 type Comment @aws_cognito_user_pool {
       id: String
       body: String
       parent: String
       createdAt: String
 }

 input CommentInput {
       id: String
       body: String
       parent: String
       createdAt: String
 }
```

In my app I am using useReducer to manage state and apollo.

My `Foo` reducer looks like so

```
const INITIAL_FOO_STATE = () => {
   name: "",
   comments: [],
}
    
export const FooReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch(action.field) {
            case "name":
            case "comments":
                return {
                    ...state, [action.field]: action.payload,
                }
            default: 
                return
        }
}
```

in my component i have the add, update and delete functions like so:

```
const addComment = (body, parent) => {
    CreateComment(
        body, 
        parent, 
    )
    .then((comment) => {
        setComments([comment, ...comments]);
        setActiveComment(null);
    });
};

const updateComment = (body, commentId) => {
    UpdateComment(body)
    .then(() => {
        const updatedComments = comments.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === commentId) {
                return {
                    ...item, 
                    body: body,
                };
            }
            return item;
        })
        setComments(updatedComments);
        setActiveComments(null);
    })
};

const deleteComment = (commentId) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this comment?")) {
        DeleteComment()
        .then(() => {
            const updatedComments = comments.filter((comment) => comment.id !== commentId);
            setComments(updatedComments)
        })
    }
};
```

This works just fine on the frontend, but now want to dispatch these actions to my Foo.comments array on the backend and looking for some help as to the best way without the need of another table.
I was thinking of placing the dispatch's within their respective .then()

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the solution was simple.
I had to modify the comment type in schema to:

```
type Comment @aws_cognito_user_pool {        
    id: ID!
    sourceId: ID!
    body: String 
    parent: String 
    createdAt: String  
}   

input CommentInput {        
    body: String 
    parent: String 
    createdAt: String  
}
```

then add the mutations and resolvers for create, update and delete of the Comment.

In the Foo comment field, a query resolver was needed.

This also meant a new table was needed for comments.

The table needed to have the `sourceId` as primary key and `ID` as sort key, with a global index setup on the sourceId
I swapped out the CRUD functions in my component with the appropriate Apollo mutations and done.